# Swi-Prolog: How to write a descendant predicate?

Tags: prolog

I have the provided definition of descendent as below:

"*a person who is in direct line to an ancestor. Eg: child,
grandchild, great-grandchild, and forever*"

and also other rules like:

```
...
childof(X, Y).
parent(X, Y).
grandchild(X, Y).
ancestor(X, Y).
...
```

So can I just simply write a rule as below,

```
descendant(X, Y):- ancestorof(Y, X).
```

or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of tree traversal or graph traversal.

I would generalize an `ancestor_of/3` predicate:

```
ancestor(Ancestor,Generations,Descendant)
```

Assuming you have, say, a set of facts like

```
parents( mother, father, child ).
```

On can say that a parent is either the mother or father of a child:

```
% P is a parent of C if P is either the mother or father of C.
parent(P,C) :- parents(P,_,C).
parent(P,C) :- parents(_,P,C).
```

And given the above, the solution might look like this:

```
ancestor(Ancestor, Generations, Descendant) :-
  ancestor( Ancestor, 0, Generations, Descendant )
  .

ancestor( A, N, G, D ) :- % A is an ancestor of D...
  parent(A,D),            % * if A is the immediate parent of D
  G is N+1                % * in which case, tick the generation count
  .                       % Easy!
ancestor( A, N, G, D ) :- % otherwise, A is an ancestor of D...
  parent(A,X),            % * if A is the immediate parent of somebody
  X \= D,                 % * other than D
  N1 is N+1,              % * [ tick the generation count]
  ancestor( X, N1, G, D ) % and that somebody is the ancestor of D
  .                       % Also easy!
```

That allows us to say things like:

```
grandparent(A,C) :- ancestor(A,2,C).

great-grandparent(A,C) :- ancestor(A,3,C).
```

etc.

This will work for biological parentage, but if you are allowing
non-biological parentage (e.g., step-parents and the like, then
"I'm my own grandpa" is a possibility, and you will need to carry
a list of visited nodes around so you can detect any cycles in the
graph.

Try to figure out how to determine different degrees of kinship from this
(what does a second cousin thrice removed look like?). You'll need to determine sibling status for starters.